# How do I fix Unknown browser query in React with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I am following a tutorial from `egghead.io` about using `React` with `Webpack`. I want to target specific browsers and only load necessary features with `Browserslist` but I am getting an `error` upon compilation.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.base.js",
    "dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "dev:hot": "npm run dev -- --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.base.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  }, 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
            targets: [
              'last 2 versions',
              'not dead',
              'not < 2 %'
            ],
            useBuiltIns: 'entry'
          }], '@babel/preset-react'],
          plugins: [
            'react-hot-loader/babel',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html'
  })]
}
```

I am getting an error when I execute `npm run build` on `terminal`. The `error` is pasted below.

```
WARNING: We noticed you're using the `useBuiltIns` option without declaring a core-js version. Currently, we assume version 2.x when no version is passed. Since this default version will likely change in future versions of Babel, we recommend explicitly setting the core-js version you are using via the `corejs` option.

You should also be sure that the version you pass to the `corejs` option matches the version specified in your `package.json`'s `dependencies` section. If it doesn't, you need to run one of the following commands:

  npm install --save core-js@2    npm install --save core-js@3
  yarn add core-js@2              yarn add core-js@3

[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to C:\Users\jason\Documents\nodeprojects\react\react-boilerplate\dist\bundle_sizes.html
assets by status 1.61 KiB [cached] 1 asset
./src/index.js 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
BrowserslistError: 
[BABEL] C:\Users\jason\Documents\nodeprojects\react\react-boilerplate\src\index.js: Unknown browser query `< 2 %`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query. (While processing: "C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\nodeprojects\\react\\react-boilerplate\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the `babel/polyfill` is deprecated by the time of this writing.

The answer was to replace `babel/polyfill` package installation with `core-js`. I then imported the `core-js` to my `index.js` file in `React`.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'core-js'
import App from './App'
import './styles.css'

// put component into html page
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

After that, I added properties in my **main webpack** file with the config below:

```
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
    targets: [
      'last 2 versions',
      'not dead',
      '> 0.2%',
      'not ie 11'
    ],
    useBuiltIns: 'entry',
    corejs: 3            
  }], '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
  ]
}
```

My entire **webpack.config.base.js** file looks like below:

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  }, 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
            targets: [
              'last 2 versions',
              'not dead',
              '> 0.2%',
              'not ie 11'
            ],
            useBuiltIns: 'entry',
            corejs: 3            
          }], '@babel/preset-react'],
          plugins: [
            'react-hot-loader/babel',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html'
  })]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's `'< 2%'`, not `'< 2 %'`, the latter is wrong.

Second, you can't start with a `not`, see https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#query-composition:

> Obviously you can not start with a not combiner, since there is no left-hand side query to combine it with.

Since you have `browserslist` installed, you can fiddle the query with command like below:

```
npx browserslist "< 2%"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to solve this issue now. You can take a look at my answer :)